# Jquery Onclick priority vs Href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a small problem to set a priority on href vs onclick:

```
 $("#table_head tr").click(function (e) {
    /* My Function */
});
```

But if I use a "href" :

```
<table id="table_head">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">my link</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How I can priorise href vs onclick please?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean that you're trying to execute some code before the page is redirected, you need to stop the normal link behaviour using `preventDefault()`, process your logic, then manually redirect the page using `window.location.assign()`. Try this:

```
$("#table_head tr").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    /* My Function */

    if (e.target.tagName == 'A') 
        window.location.assign(e.target.href);
});
```